# Find all files added by a Git user?

Tags: git

In Git, how can I simply find all of the files that were added to a repository by a particular user?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
git whatchanged --author="author regexp" --diff-filter=A --no-commit-id --name-only
```

Better methods are likely to be available.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use below command:

```
 git whatchanged --diff-filter=A --author=AUTHOR --pretty=format:%an | awk '{print $6}'
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the current documentation (v2.41.0), new users are encouraged to use [git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---authorltpatterngt) instead of [git-whatchanged](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged).

Here's the modified version of the originally accepted answer from 12 years ago:

```
git log --author=AUTHOR --format="" --diff-filter=A --name-only --no-commit-id
```